# When I read data from firebase, it show my data. But it also show all user data. Not only my data. But I want only my data. Not other user

Tags: flutter

For Write Data. Here is the code. I call data from `users` account. But there are multiple user data. I only show my data. But it shows all user data.

```
  getDriversList() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();
  }

 QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDriversList().then((results) {
      setState(() {
        querySnapshot = results;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please follow the user submission guidelines in order to properly submit questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help.  In the meantime, I would  look and see if you can add a select clause to 'return await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();'

Answer (score 0):

You can use userId as documentID when create those users document.
Then call`await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(your user Id).get();` to get users own data.

Comment: I use user id. But it dos't work.
createUserFirestore() async{
      GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
      DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(user.id).get();
    if(!doc.exists){
      final username = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CreateAccount()));
      final userphone = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CreateAccount()));

      userRef.document(user.id).setData({
        'id':user.id,